# How can I stop an image from flickering when updating the source in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am making a game in JavaScript. When the player's health is below 50, I want the source of an image on the canvas to be updated. When the image changes, there is a flicker. How can I stop this from happening when the image source is changed?

**This is my code:**

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
let canvas;
let ctx;

let player;
let img;

window.onload = function () {
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  player = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    color: "#000000",
    health: 100
  }
  img = new Image();

  function draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = player.color;
    ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }

  function gameLoop() {
    if (player.health < 50) img.src = "img1";
    else img.src = "img2";
    
    draw();

    requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
}
```

Comment: Try preloading the image - the flicker is probably the time it takes to download the new image

Comment: Try having two different image objects and instead passing the object to the draw function rather than explicitly labelling the variables.